# NO-BREAK SPACE python2.* convert to UTF-8

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x, utf-8

В скрипте в определённый момент появляется строка, содержащая NO-BREAK SPACE (0xa0). При попытке сконвертировать строку в utf-8 получаю следующую ошибку:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Исходная строка - передаваемый аргумент, считываемый через RegeneratableOptionParser с type='path'

Comment: Таблица ASCII заканчивается кодом 0x7F. Вам нужно декодировать не из ASCII, а из той кодировки, в которую этот NO-BREAK SPACE входит.

Comment: К примеру, `'1234\xa0qwerty'.decode('cp1251')` (или cp1252) такой ошибки не дает.